# (IE Specific) How to determine if entered text is longer then input element's width

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This is an IE specific issue, all versions.
In all other browsers the scrollWidth of the input element is greater then the clientWidth of the input element when the text overflows.

Is there a way to determine that the text in the input field has overflowed the bonds of the input element width in IE?

Below is a simple example to check the clientWidth vs the scrollWidth

```js
var myInput = document.body.querySelector('#myInput');
myInput.value = 'Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem';

function checkInputSize() {
    alert('Client Width: ' + myInput.clientWidth + '\n' +
          'Scroll Width: ' + myInput.scrollWidth);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="myInput"></input>
</div>

<button onclick="checkInputSize()"
        style="margin-top: 2em;">
    <span>Display Input Size</span>
</button>
```

I am hoping there is a more straight forward way to determine the above without requiring faithful replication of styles to another element. I understand that it may be the 'best' option but I really wanted to give IE the benefit of the doubt that it was better than that.

If I need to replicate the styles the best bet would be to use window.getComputedStyle, although IE8 does not support this feature that is not a concern to me.

```
var getJsStyleName = function(styleName) {
    var firstCharacterRegex = new RegExp('^.');
    styleName = styleName.split('-');
    for (var i = 1; i < styleName.length; i++) {
        styleName[i] = styleName[i].replace(firstCharacterRegex, styleName[i][0].toUpperCase());
    }
    return styleName.join('');
};

var copyComputedStyles = function(toElement, fromElement) {
    var comStyle = window.getComputedStyle(fromElement) );
    for (var i = 0; i < comStyle.length; i++) {
        var styleName = getJsStyleName(comStyle[i]);
        toElement.style[ styleName ] = comStyle[ styleName ];
    }

    return toElement;
}


var inputStyledDiv = copyComputedStyles(document.createElement('div'), inputElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've examined all computed styles in IE using text that does and does not overflow the input box.  All styles are identical.

An alternative is to duplicate the input contents within a div, and see if its clientWidth is wider than the input's clientWidth.  You have to be careful to duplicate all the input's styles within the div.

The code below does so by iterating through `myInput`'s `currentStyle`.  This property is not available in Chrome, in which case it reverts to your `scrollWidth` > `clientWidth` logic.

```
function checkInputSize() {
  var contents= document.querySelector('#contents');
  var output= document.querySelector('#output');
  var st= myInput.currentStyle;
  if(st) {
    for(var i in st) {
      contents.style[i]= st[i];
    }
    contents.innerHTML= myInput.value;

    output.innerHTML= contents.clientWidth+(contents.clientWidth >= myInput.clientWidth ? ': overflow' : '');
    contents.style.display= 'none';
  }
  else {
    output.innerHTML= myInput.scrollWidth+(myInput.scrollWidth > myInput.clientWidth ? ': overflow' : '');
  }
}
```

### Fiddle

Comment: I had considered the duplication of styles the input elements has to a DIV to test if the length of the text overflows but I really hoped there was a more straight forward way.