# ScrollWidth returning same value in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input which adjusts the font size when the value exceeds the width of the input. This works perfectly in Firefox or Chrome, but not in IE.
I've searched far and wide and it looks like IE has a problem with scrollwidth; it always returns the same value.

How would i make this work in IE.
https://jsfiddle.net/BelgoCanadian/k1xpnvxL/
Please use Chrome or Firefox to see it working.

```
function autoSize() {
    var defaultFont = 20
    var tbx = $('#textbox')
    //Parsing necessary to get rid of "px"
    var fontSize = parseFloat(tbx.css("font-size").substring(0,  tbx.css("font-size").length - 2))
    //While loop to decrease font until it fits in the textbox
    while (tbx[0].scrollWidth > tbx[0].clientWidth) {
      fontSize = fontSize - 1;
      tbx.css("font-size", fontSize + 'px')
    }
    //While loop to increase font back to default font size
    while (tbx[0].scrollWidth === tbx[0].clientWidth && fontSize < defaultFont) {
      fontSize = fontSize + 1;
      tbx.css("font-size", fontSize + 'px')
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(IE Specific) How to determine if entered text is longer then input element's width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829233/ie-specific-how-to-determine-if-entered-text-is-longer-then-input-elements-wi)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix the IE/Edge `scrollWidth` issue with a thingy called [scrollWidthPolyfill](https://github.com/gregwhitworth/scrollWidthPolyfill).

I noticed that it is not particularly robust – ie, it breaks when you load the script in the head of the document. So append it to the body, which is a best practice anyway.

But it works. See [this demo on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cuwibo/1). You'll have to iron out a few kinks in your own code, though, as you'll see when you run the demo in IE.